# Why is my Ubuntu installer crashing whenever im trying to install Ubuntu?

Tags: 19.10

I'm having a problem installing Ubuntu, Whenever I try to install Ubuntu, Before I get to the Erase data thing, The installer crashes completely, Saying something along the lines of "(bug) failure creating named object" 
Btw I use a USB to install ubuntu.
Cheers,
Laith.

Comment: How much memory has the target machine?  I get that when there is insufficient memory.

Comment: @cup My laptop has 8 GB of memory, and the Website said that the recommended amount is 4 GB (i think).

Comment: Did you verify your downloaded ISO to ensure it was perfect (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0) and then after writing to your install media, ensure the write was flawless? (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck where CD refers to whatever media was used, inc. CD/DVD/HDD/SSD/thumb-drive/memory-card/etc)